# MATLAB - Finding Zero of Sum of Functions by Iteration

Tags: matlab, function, sum, root, series

I am trying to sum a function and then attempting to find the root of said function. That is, for example, take:

Consider that I have a matrix,X, and vector,t, of values: X(2*n+1,n+1), t(n+1)

```
for j = 1:n+1
        sum = 0;
    for i = 1:2*j+1
        f = @(g)exp[-exp[X(i,j)+g]*(t(j+1)-t(j))];
        sum = sum + f;
    end
        fzero(sum,0)
end
```

That is,

I want to evaluate at

j = 1

```
f = @(g)exp[-exp[X(1,1)+g]*(t(j+1)-t(j))]
fzero(f,0)
```

j = 2

```
f = @(g)exp[-exp[X(1,2)+g]*(t(j+1)-t(j))] + exp[-exp[X(2,2)+g]*(t(j+1)-t(j))] + exp[-exp[X(3,2)+g]*(t(j+1)-t(j))]
fzero(f,0)
```

j = 3

etc...

However, I have no idea how to actually implement this in practice.

Any help is appreciated!

PS - I do not have the symbolic toolbox in Matlab.

Comment: Is this about arbitrary functions or only about polynomials? For the later case use `roots`

Comment: It's not really about arbitrary functions (although I would like to see how that would work), but this particular function that I am dealing with - which isn't specifically a polynomial.

Comment: You have some bad syntax errors, with `exp[]`. Please reconsider your code. Oh, OK, I guess this is pseudocode... Well, you can't sum anonymous functions, but you *can* use something like `sum = @(x) sum(x) +f(x);`. Just watch out for the recursion limit, and expect it to be *very* slow.

Comment: @AndrasDeak you actually endorsing calling a variable `sum`?

Comment: @Adriaan haha, yeah, right. *Don't use `sum` as a variable!*. And while we're at it: drop `i,j` as well.

Comment: Oddly, you can use sum as a variable as you can see from my example on the bottom.

Comment: @user5619709 that's not odd, it's expected behaviour, since you can overwrite built-in function. You just seriously should not do that. You can no longer use the native MATLAB function `sum` anymore in your program, since you elected to give a very useful and descriptive variable name that happens to exactly coincide with `sum`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest making use of matlab's array operations:

```
zerovec = zeros(1,n+1); %preallocate
for k = 1:n+1
    f = @(y) sum(exp(-exp(X(1:2*k+1,k)+y)*(t(k+1)-t(k))));
    zerovec(k) = fzero(f,0);
end
```

However, note that the sum of exponentials will never be zero, unless the exponent is complex. Which `fzero` will never find, so the question is a bit of a moot point.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is to write a function:

```
 function [ sum ] = func(j,g,t,X)
    sum = 0;
    for i = 0:2*j
        f = exp(-exp(X(i+1,j+1)+g)*(t(j+3)-t(j+2)));
        sum = sum + f;
    end
 end
```

Then loop your solver

```
for j=0:n
  fun = @(g)func(j,g,t,X);
  fzero(fun,0)
end
```

Comment: As we said, don't use `sum` as a variable. As you said, you *can*. Just *shouldn't*. Try computing the sum of the first 5 integers at the end of your function: `sum(1:5)`.

Comment: So, the issue with the method that I posted - is it that I used a variable called "sum" or the fact that I am indeed summing to create the function. As I said, it works when implemented in this manner (so long as the sum exists within the function itself, contrary to what I started the thread with).

Comment: Your answer works, and answers your question, so no issues there. We have an unrelated problem: defining a variable named `sum` will *shadow* the built-in function `sum` of matlab. If you were to sum the values in an array `arr`, you'd use `sum(arr)`. But once you define a variable named `sum`, anything looking like `sum(arr)` will be interpreted as an indexing operation on the variable `sum`, leading to either gibberish, or indexing errors.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification. I have a bad habit of using predefined words/functions in my codes...

Comment: Well, overriding such built-ins can lead to nasty surprises:) A lot of "Error: Index exceeds matrix dimensions" kind of questions here on SO are due to this problem. This is why we regularly advise against using built-in function names as variable names, and it's related (but less clear-cut) why you shouldn't use `i` and `j` either (since those are both the imaginary unit, which is also accessible as `1i`, `1j`...).